# Using Javascript function with WT(Witty).

Tags: javascript, d3.js, wt

I'm exploring to embedded D3/DC visualizations with WT(Witty) Webpage. 
Is it possible to use javascript functions with WT?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes you can.You can use `jsslot` and call the javascript code by `WApplication::doJavaScript()`.

Please have a look [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.witty.general/3215).